# json support in REST

Tags: json, rest

I am working in RESTAPI. We have XML schema with abstract types. We have added @Mapped annotation to support json.

But still we get JAXB binding exception while doing POST Operations. But the GET operation works fine for JSON. What needs to be done in this case?

We are using jettison library.

For JAX-RS implemetation,we are using RESTEasy library.JAXB generated classes resides inside the package "net.com.schema.services".

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Mapped(namespaceMap = {
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "services.schema.com.net", jsonName = ""),
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", jsonName = "")
})
@Path(ID_REGEX)
@RBAC(type = { CRUDEnum.READ }, capability = { "APICap" })
public JAXBElement<RESTOperationType> getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int customerId);

@POST
@Path(CUSTOMERS)
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Mapped(namespaceMap = {
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "services.schema.com.net ", jsonName = ""),
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", jsonName = "")
})
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
@RBAC(type = { CRUDEnum.CREATE }, capability = { "APICap" })
public JAXBElement<RESTOperationType> addCustomer(JAXBElement<RESTOperationType> restOprn)
```

I tried the above code and i got binding exception for POST Operation.I tried another approach.

```
@POST
@Path(CUSTOMERS)
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
@Mapped(namespaceMap = {
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "services.schema.com.net ", jsonName = ""),
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", jsonName = "")
})
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
@RBAC(type = { CRUDEnum.CREATE }, capability = { "APICap" })
public JAXBElement<RESTOperationType> addCustomer(@Mapped(namespaceMap = {
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "services.schema.com.net ", jsonName = ""),
@XmlNsMap(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", jsonName = "")
})JAXBElement<RESTOperationType> restOprn);
```

I gave @Mapped annotation inside the addCustomer method.Now , Binding exception is resolved and am getting NullPointer exception while attempting to read data from JSON input.

Comment: What library are you using? Jersey?

Comment: 1). What lib are you using for JAX-RS implementation? 2). Attach a code snippet please.